# Xamarin Android delete contact

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm building an Android application using Xamarin that will add and remove contacts on the phone.

I would like to be able to only delete the contacts I've added.

I've search the Xamarin documentation and Stackoverflow and I did not find how to delete a contact using Xamarin Android.

How can I delete a contact?
What field can I use to store a key so that I can recognize the contacts added by my application (Id, LookupKey, another one?)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to lookup key this method should do the trick.

```
public static void DeleteContact(Context context, string lookupKey)
{
    var uri = Uri.WithAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentLookupUri, lookupKey);
    context.ContentResolver.Delete(uri, null, null);
}
```